# C, trouble reading .bmp

Tags: c, bitmap

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

void main(void) 
{ 
  char path_bmp [100]; 
  char path_txt [100]; 
  int w; //width 
  int h; //height 
  int wc; //width counter 
  int hc; //height counter 
  FILE *bfp; //BMP pointer 
  FILE *tfp; //TXT pointer 

  puts("BMP path"); 
  gets(path_bmp); 
  puts("Resulting TXT path"); 
  gets(path_txt); 

  bfp = fopen(path_bmp, "r"); 
  tfp = fopen(path_txt, "w"); 

  fseek(bfp, 18, SEEK_SET); 
  fscanf(bfp, "%i", &w); 
  fseek(bfp, 4, SEEK_CUR); 
  fscanf(bfp, "%i", &h); 
  printf("%i x %i", w, h); 

  char mat [w][h]; 
  fseek(bfp, 54, SEEK_SET); 

  for(hc=0; hc < h; hc++)
      fread(mat, 1, w, bfp); 

  for(hc=0; hc < h; hc++) 
      for(wc=0; wc < w; wc++) 
      { 
          if (mat [wc][hc] == 0) 
              fprintf(tfp, " "); 
          else
              fprintf(tfp, "o"); 
      } 

  fprintf(tfp, "\n"); 
}
```

What it's intended to do: 
It converts a .bmp into ASCII-art, not very complicated, just pretty simple black and white pics.
It should read .bmp, get height and width from header, read all pixels byte by byte into matrix(**mat** array), then write space into text file if pixel is white and write "0" if pixel is any color but white.

What it actually does: 
It is reading w and h from some wrong place. 
On `printf("%i x %i", w, h);` it prints out some large numbers (I use small pics for testing, like 10x6 px) and then crashes, with process returning even larger number. As far as I can see, the program is clearly reading from some garbage instead of where it should read and I can't get why (spent lots of time trying to figure it out).

Also, I have a feel that I'm doing something wrong when reading to array/writing from array, so pointing out those flaws would be greatly appreciated.

UPD: Thank you, guys, you helped me greatly!

Comment: what is `fseek(bfp, 18, SEEK_SET);`  ??? why do you do this?

Comment: For scanf and printf, if you're dealing with `int`, you want `%d`, not `%i`.

Comment: welp. Picture's width is stored at 18th byte of the file, so I move the pointer to the 18th byte. Doesn't look wrong to me, to be honest.

%d gives the same error(already tried), but thank you anyway.

Comment: Actually, I take it back, you don't want either.  Scanf scans a string, such as "12345" and converts it to an int.  Instead, you want to read the values, since they're already stored as binary, right?

Comment: Is the width stored as ascii or binary? scanf() is meant to read ascii files.

Comment: Yup, I thought about this, but(wtf, lol, this is incredibly stupid) I did not manage to google how to read binaries.

Comment: "c read binary file" seems to Google ok to me.  Namely, you'll use a lot of calls to `fread`.  Also, note that this will increment the read pointer in your FILE structure, so e.g. in the case of reading width then height, you won't need any `fseek`.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein Thanks a lot, I will try that when I'll get to my computer. 
Any comments on the rest of the code? I surely did something wrong in the part when program writes pixels to .txt

Comment: I can see a few potential issues, but isn't the fun of learning seeing them and fixing them yourself?  ;-)  (Offhand, I'd make the mat be [h][w] instead of [w][h] - and allocate it right, watch your fread - it's always only reading into the first line of the matrix.  You can fix that by just freading `w x h` all at once.)

Comment: The basic logic in the function (aside from errors that have already been pointed out) will only read 8-bit .bmp files correctly.  There is also a format for 24-bit which has 3 bytes per pixel (BGR) and where each row of pixels stored in the file is padded to a length in bytes that is an integer multiple of 4.

Comment: *All* bmp flavours' scan lines are padded to 4 bytes ... to add to @willus notes: the image is stored upside-down as well. You can live with that (if you don't mind, or your input image is flipped vertically before reading, or you flip the output); or read from last to first scan line and store in the  orrect order while reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appear to have some problems with your code, including some basic stuff about C.
I commented some errors that I caught at a first glance, but there may be some more.
I would also recommend you to take a look at the [bitmap format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_Independent_Bitmap), specially at the section that describes the padding added to the end of each line.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

void main(void) 
{ 
    char path_bmp [100]; 
    char path_txt [100]; 
    int w; //width 
    int h; //height 
    int wc; //width counter 
    int hc; //height counter 
    FILE *bfp; //BMP pointer 
    FILE *tfp; //TXT pointer 

    puts("BMP path"); 
    gets(path_bmp); 
    puts("Resulting TXT path"); 
    gets(path_txt); 

    bfp = fopen(path_bmp, "r"); 
    tfp = fopen(path_txt, "w"); 

    fseek(bfp, 18, SEEK_SET); 
    fread(&w, sizeof(int), 1, bfp); // Read the width in binary format (signed integer)
    fread(&h, sizeof(int), 1, bfp); // The position indicator of the stream is advanced by the total amount of bytes read (sizeof(int)).

    printf("%i x %i", w, h); 

    pixel mat [w][h]; //This can be a packed structure or a union, so you can read all 3 color components with one fread() call

    fseek(bfp, 54, SEEK_SET); 

    for(hc=0; hc < h; hc++)
    {
        for(wc=0; wc < w; wc++) 
        { 
            /* Note that you have to read three bytes, since every pixel has 3 color components*/
            fread(mat[wc][hc].red, sizeof(char), 1, bfp);
            fread(mat[wc][hc].green, sizeof(char), 1, bfp);
            fread(mat[wc][hc].blue, sizeof(char), 1, bfp);
        }
        // you need to do a fseek() here, in order to advance the padding added to the end of each line defined in .BMP format
        fprintf(tfp, "\n"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: The `char mat[w][h]` *is* legal in C(99), take a look at [Variable-length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)

Comment: @fvdalcin -- As it stands now, there is nothing in your function to read the data from the bitmap into the mat[][] array.

Comment: That's true, I changed it now. And I also forgot that every pixel has 3 color components, which are stored one after another in an array fashion. I've already coded a bitmap file to matrix reader which worked, I'll take a look at that later and see if everything here works fine.

Answer (score 2):

`fscanf` with `%i` reads an integer as a sequence of ASCII digits, but the width & height of the BMP are stored in raw binary. Use [`fread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) instead to read them:

```
fread(&w, 1, 4, bfp); 
fread(&h, 1, 4, bfp);
```

(`fseek` isn't necessary before reading the height as the previous `fread` already advances the stream pointer. Which is also the case for `fscanf`)

As the width & height are specified to be 4 bytes it's recommended to use `int32_t` instead of `int` as the type to make sure it will always fit exactly.